# Printing certain element in a nested list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, nested-lists

I have a function where it prints runtime totals between a low and high value. I have created a powerset function and used that in my new runtime function.

Within those new sets that are between the low and high, I need to print the names of the movies. I'm having trouble printing all the titles. I've tried using the same for loop, but I couldn't figure it out. So, I've kept the i.

```
def show_marathon_options(movies, low, high):
    sets = power_set(movies)
    count = 1
    for i in sets:
        runtime = 0
        for j in i:
            runtime += j[1]
        if low <= runtime <= high:
            print(f'{count}. Total runtime for {i}: {runtime} mins.')
            count += 1
```

input:

```
movie_20 = [['Back to the Future', 116], ['How to Train Your Dragon', 98], ['The Land Before Time', 69],
                ['The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 201], ['Tangled', 100], ['Titanic', 194],
                ['The Godfather', 202], ['Schindler''s List', 195], ['The Green Mile', 189],
                ['Fanny and Alexander', 188], ['Avengers: Endgame', 181], ['The Wolf of Wall Street', 180],
                ['Casino', 178], ['Braveheart', 178], ['Interstellar', 169], ['Django Unchained', 165],
                ['Saving Private Ryan', 169], ['Logan', 137], ['Tarzan', 88], ['Mulan', 88]]
```

output:

```
1. Total runtime for [['Back to the Future', 116], ['How to Train Your Dragon', 98]]: 214 mins.
2. Total runtime for [['Back to the Future', 116], ['The Land Before Time', 69]]: 185 mins.
3. Total runtime for [['Back to the Future', 116], ['How to Train Your Dragon', 98], ['The Land Before Time', 69]]: 283 mins.
4. Total runtime for [['The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 201]]: 201 mins.
5......
```

Needed format output:

```
1. Total runtime for Back to the Future, How to Train Your Dragon: 214 mins.
2. Total runtime for Back to the Future, The Land Before Time: 185 mins.
3. Total runtime for Back to the Future, How to Train Your Dragon, The Land Before Time: 283 mins.
4. Total runtime for The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King': 201 mins.
5....
```

I've tried j[0], but it only accesses the first title of every line.

Comment: Try, `', '.join(movie[0] for movie in i)`. rather than just `i` in the `print()` statement? You need to iterate over the elements of `i`.

Comment: No problem, will write a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `', '.join(movie[0] for movie in i)`, rather than just `i` in the `print()` statement. You need to iterate over the elements of `i`.